# I can't get xdebug to start, it doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I really need your help...

I've been trying to do Xdebug on my VSC for 2 days.
I have reinstalled the wamp 20 times and nothing.
I have changed the php.ini 100 times and nothing.
Nothing in the xdebug.log

Use the xdebugger wizard
It shows up fine in the phpinfo

I need your help!!!!!!!!!!!

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
;xdebug.mode allowed are : off develop coverage debug gcstats profile trace
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.log=C:/wamp64/tmp/xdebug.log
```

---

settings.jaison

---

```
{
"php.validate.enable": true,
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.26/php.exe",
"php.validate.run": "onSave",
"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
}
```

---

```
      "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        
            {
                "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "port": 9003,
            },
    
            {
                "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
                "type": "php",
                "request": "launch",
                "runtimeArgs": [
                    "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                    "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                    "-S",
                    "localhost:0"
                ],
                "program": "",
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "port": 9003,
                "serverReadyAction": {
                    "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                    "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                    "action": "openExternally"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: xdebug.mode is commented out. For stepping through code, it should be 'develop' (out of my head)

Comment: Thanks for answering

`; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.mode = on
xdebug.start_with_request = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.output_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.log=C:/wamp64/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.force_display_errors = 1`

Comment: Now every time I boot wamp

php_error.log

`[20-Feb-2022 06:44:34 UTC] Xdebug: [Config] Invalid mode '1' set for 'xdebug.mode' configuration setting ( https://xdebug.org/docs/errors#CFG-C-MODE)`

Comment: now you have 2 time xdebug.mode. One set to `debug` and one set to `on` which is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The setting names and values in Xdebug 3 have changed, please read the [Upgrade Guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and go through your current settings one by one.